# CSS question: why my css stylesheet selector not working?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="graphicArea">
    <div id="page1" class="pageArea land"></div>
    <div id="page2" class="pageArea land"></div>
</div>
```

my CSS stylesheet file snippet (this works):

```
.pageArea {
    width:220px!important;
    height:210px!important; 
 }
```

my CSS stylesheet file snippet (this don't work):

```
.pageArea.land {
    width:220px!important;
    height:210px!important; 
 }
```

neitheir this works:

```
div.pageArea.land {
    width:220px!important;
    height:210px!important; 
 }
```

There is not much in this file further on, so I'm pretty sure it's not overriding the css.
Anyone know why cant it work?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

All this css is within @media print { .. }. I don't think its relevant though.

**EDIT2**

Does FF has any issue regarding setting a div height/width in mm? I guess that's the whole point...

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use !important?  It makes things very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Poor CSS usually results in having to use !important, due to the definitions being in the wrong order. I see it too often, and I think it should only be used in very rare scenarios.

Comment: @media print - you are printing out the document then, correct?

Comment: @Austin Fitzpatrick It's currently not necessary on this div to use important. I've tried it without it but no success.

Comment: @Pekka Yes I'm trying to print the document. If I use .pageArea { }, it works. I'm not getting the point... =?

Comment: @Iara just making sure you know what @media print is for. (Nothing personal, but we have all sorts here on SO :)

Comment: @Jesse Dhillon You are right. It's capital that I have to get deep into stylesheet design and organization. It has been a long time since I've last worked developing for web. The problem also is that there is a third party company who designed all the html code and webdesign of the application, and we are just working under the hood. So we must be subject to their design and stylization.

Comment: @Pekka No prob.! All help provided is welcomed :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html), your code should work. Are you using Internet Explorer 6?

edit 1: .class1.class2 works with Chrome, and probably other browsers as well. Are you sure your selector is not working? Try "display: none" to be really sure.

Comment: So are you sure your CSS selector is not working? I'm pretty sure it's working but you think it isn't because it's overridden or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

`.pageArea.land` means that the element you're targeting has 2 classes, `pageArea` and `land`.

How is your HTML laid out? Is `.land` a child of `.pageArea`? If so you just need a space between them, i.e.

`.pageArea .land {
   ....
}`

Comment: Well now that you've provided html, my answer isn't valid and has been answered by others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <div id="page1" class="pageArea land"></div>


.pageArea {
    width:220px!important;
    height:210px!important; 
 }

.land {
    width:220px!important;
    height:210px!important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the dot of land in the pageArea , It must look like `div.pageArea, .land`

Comment: @laramaki you need to show some HTML. Everything done here is guesswork otherwise.

Comment: seperate them with comma. In fact It would help us if you inform what you try to achieve because your code seems very strange with all these `!important`.

Comment: The HTML in the question has `class="pageArea land"` so this is incorrect -- the OP wants to select and element with *two* CSS classes, not nested elements (which would require a space) or elements with either one or the other class (which would require a comma).

Comment: I read it first time this with comma :O can you provide me link that explain further your whole comment? I am very curious about this..

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a space between .pageArea.land like this .pageArea .land  You can try the following css structure
div#page1 .pageArea{
    css goes here
}

div#page1 .land{
    css goes here
}

div#page2 .pageArea{
    css goes here
}

div#page2 .land{
    css goes here
}

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to determine which styles are influencing the final appearance of these elements, once the cascade is applied.

Given the small snips HTML and CSS you've given us, it looks alright, yet you are telling us that you're not getting the desired result. Add to that your superfluous use of `!important`, and I think it's safe to conclude that your stylesheet contains many conflicting properties that aren't shown in your code sample, and one or more of them are influencing `.pageArea.land`.

Comment: The problem is I think I cant use firebug because those css are just used for printing. Even more, the class land is just added on runtime for purposes of printing and is not referenced nowhere else in the code.

Comment: For debugging purposes, apply the stylesheet to screen instead of print, and add the `pageArea land` class attribute to the element using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT All this css is within @media print { .. }. I don't think its relevant though.

If it's in `@media print { }` the css will be applied when PRINTING

To have it be applied in the browser use `@media screen { }`

And if you want to see it in both print and on screen use `@media screen, print { }`